# source code analyzer for pthread_mutex types (and lock/unlock balancing)

Tags: linux, api, multi-threading, static-code-analysis

For the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (Linux/x86-64, GPLv3+ licensed), its [refpersys-in-c](https://github.com/RefPerSys/refpersys-in-c) variant, [commit 1441e0fa148d](https://github.com/RefPerSys/refpersys-in-c/commit/1441e0fa148dbfe388b5eeb0f81d6bc7da43843c), I am seeking a source code analyzer which checks that calls to `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` are well balanced.

I am aware that in general the question is undecidable ([Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)'s theorem).

For [refpersys-in-c](https://github.com/RefPerSys/refpersys-in-c) the C code should be "simple enough" to be probably analyzable in practice by simple automatic tools. We tried hard to avoid complex control flows.

Most `pthread_mutex_t` are either global or static, or inside the `RpsObject_t` type (defined in [header `Refpersys.h`](https://github.com/RefPerSys/refpersys-in-c/blob/main/Refpersys.h) as `struct  RpsZoneObject_st`)

Comment: Sonarsource comes with some rules for pthreads. https://rules.sonarsource.com/c Did you look at that? I didn't use it myself yet. I also saw that Clang compiler has some rule set for pthreads.